# Div results nesting in one another

Tags: php, html

I have some code which takes my results from the database and then wraps them in to a div, so that each of the results are situated in to individual boxes.

Whilst the results are fine, the problem i am having is that the boxes are repeating inside one another and not formating in to individual boxes which list below one another.

below is my php code

```
   $sVisit_Id='';
         while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)) {
               $url1  = $row['url1'];

                 if ($row['visit_id']!=$sVisit_Id)
                    {

                      echo '</table>'; 
                      ?> <div class="box1095"><?php
                      echo '<table><tr><td class="test" width="350px;"><strong>'.$referrer.'</strong><br /></td><td>'.$search_term.'</td></tr><table>';

                      $sVisit_Id=$row['visit_id'];
                      echo '<tr bgcolor="#333" height=30px"><td width="200px">Date/Time</td><td width="750px">Webpage</td><td width="150px"></td></tr>';
                    }

                      echo '<tr class="active" bgcolor="" onMouseOver="this.bgColor="gold";" onMouseOut="this.bg"#222222";"><td width="200px" border="">'.$row['timedate'].
   '</td><td width="750px" border="">'. $row['url1'].'</td><td width="15px" align="right" border="">'. "<a href=". $url1 ." class=''> " ?><img src="images/go_button.fw.png" width="100" height="30" alt="GO" target="_blank"/><?php "</a>" .'</td></tr>';
         } ?></div><?php 

                     echo '</table>';
```

The image below shows a screenshot of the results.

[image: Results Screenshot]

Any suggestions or guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `<?php "</a>" .'</td></tr>';` You are not echoing this line out, so your cells never close before adding the next one.

Comment: `</a></td></tr>` are available at the end, scroll right.

Comment: @RecoveringSince2003 They are not being echoed, just declared.

Comment: @David, I can see `echo` before each line of `tr...`.

Comment: @RecoveringSince2003 look at the 4th line from the bottom of his code. At the very end, it says `<?php "</a>" .'</td></tr>';` That is not being echoed, just declared.

Comment: @David, I still didn't get it, can you paste the line ?

Comment: '</td><td width="750px" border="">'. $row['url1'].'</td><td width="15px" align="right" border="">'. "<a href=". $url1 ." class=''> " ?><img src="images/go_button.fw.png" width="100" height="30" alt="GO" target="_blank"/><?php "</a>" .'</td></tr>'; At the very end of the line, he doesn't echo the string.

Comment: @David, now I can see and updated the answer as well, thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this

```
echo '<table>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)) {
    // everything goes here
    echo '<tr><td>Webpage</td><td></td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td>some text</td><td>some text</td><td><a href=""><img src="" /></a></td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Keep `table` out of the loop (both, starting and closing tags), so, there will be one table with multiple rows (`tr`).

**Update :** You have (`<table>...<table>`) between `if` condition, as given below

```
echo '<table><tr><td class="test" width="350px;"><strong>'.$referrer.'</strong><br /></td><td>'.$search_term.'</td></tr><table>';
```

There is no closing tag, instead you have `<table>` so, your table is never closed. Also, there is only `echo '</table>';` at the beginning of `if` condition, without starting tag (within loop) but closing tag is outside of loop.

**Update :** Also you have following (pointed out by `David`) at the end of your last line within the loop, (not echoed/printed).

```
<?php "</a>" .'</td></tr>';
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I inherited the page and all of the problems from a previous developer.  i have changed the points you raised but the issue still existed, i have rebuilt the page to reflect your comments but the problem lays in grouping the results to the visitor_id